# tcpTransport + encryption + compression + windows authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, encryption, windows-authentication, nettcpbinding

Here's  what I need:

- Compression -> requires Custom Binding
- NetTcpBinding
- Encryption
- User's Windows Username (Windows Authentication is fine, but it has to be non-blocking)

It seems almost impossible to get these all work together.

However now I think I got close, but this still doesn't work across domains. I don't want Windows Authentication to block access to Web Service as it currently does. I just need to know user's identity and offer data based on that. There are also some methods that require anonymous access.

```
  <bindings>
<customBinding>
  <binding name="ZipBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
    <customMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="binaryMessageEncoding" messageEncoderType="WcfExtensions.GZipMessageEncoder, WcfExtensions">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999" maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999">
      </readerQuotas>
    </customMessageEncoding>
    <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
    <tcpTransport maxBufferSize="999999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

And why EncryptAndSign doesn't require certificate? It uses SSL to encrypt messages, right?
I would be happy to use sslStreamSecurity, but it didn't work either.

I suppose my current solution uses message security? Transport security would be more than enough and it would also be faster, but I'm not exaclty sure what I then would have to change